# How to adjust datatimepicker popup position? datetimepicker in modal

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

when I use datetimepicker for my input, I found some positioning issue with it, can I change the popup position when I setting up the datetimepicker?

I try to find documentations about how to adjust position, but I failed.

```
$('#right_start_time').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
});

<input type="text" class="select-input" id="left_start_time">
```

What i expect:

```
$('#right_start_time').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    position: right_under_the_input,
});
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see, I the datetimepicker is out of range,

Comment: solved already,